# Datastax Opscenter shows empty storage capacity

Tags: datastax, cassandra-2.0, opscenter

I'm using opscenter free edition 4.0.2, with cassandra 2.0.3 on centos 6.
The storage capacity widget on the landing page is showing no data at all. 
The storage-capacity call is returning:

{"free_gb": 0, "used_gb": 0, "reporting_nodes": 0}

However in the cluster ring view size is shown correctly.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The call says `reporting_nodes: 0` means that there are currently no nodes actively attached to Opscenter.

This can be fixed by [installing Opscenter agent](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.0/webhelp/index.html#opsc/install/../../opsc/install/installingAgents.html) on each of your machines.

Look for this image in Opscenter, and click 'Fix'.

[image]